# Good starting options for FFmpeg with hevc_videotoolbox?

Tags: video, encoding

I am using the latest FFmpeg from MacPorts, and I have a new MacbookPro running macOS Mojave.

I was wondering what are good options to start with to use the hevc_videotoolbox encoder?

I did a quick search of the web, but I mostly found a lot of guesswork and several reports that the quality of the videotoolbox encoder is not as good as the software encoder x265.

What I would need are three sets of options :

1. OK-ish quality, fast encoding;
2. Good quality, fast encoding, at most 1/2 file size of the original H.264 video (on average)
3. High quality, file size < H264 file size, encoding time does not matter very much.

Currently, I am converting videos using this set of options:

```
/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel level+info -hide_banner -nostats -nostdin -strict -2 -probesize 50M -analyzeduration 100M -i input.avi -map 0 -map -0:v:1 -c:s copy -map_metadata 0 -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v -dn -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a -c:a aac_at -b:a 128k -profile:a aac_eld -filter:v crop=in_w-mod(in_w\,2):in_h-mod(in_h\,2) -codec:v libx265 -tag:v hvc1 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -vf format=yuv420p10le -preset faster -crf 25 -x265-params profile=main10:me=hex:qcomp=0.5:ref=4:psy-rd=2.0:psy-rdoq=1.0:rd=6:log-level=2 -ignore_unknown -f mp4 output.mp4
```

But a quick test showed that using videotoolbox, conversion could be significantly faster while using much less energy at the same time.

But I am a bit at a loss as to what would be good options for the hevc_videotoolbox encoder such that the output quality is comparable to that of my current conversion settings.

Note that I would like to stick with FFmpeg (at least for the time being). Also, I am only asking about ways to run FFmpeg on a MacbookPro.

Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The reason why I would like to explore this encoder is that, at least with a very  quick and dumb test, I found that it is ~4 times  faster and uses only ~ 1/4 of the energy of the x265 encoder.

Comment: I have tried to improve my question (see above).